# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when trying to run SmackCcsClient for CCS

Tags: java, android, json, xmpp

I am trying to make third party server so that I can implement CCS server for my chat client. I copied the below code from below android developer link, I included Smack library and JSON library as prescribed, however I am getting compilation error.

[CCS Link](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html)

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketInterceptor;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException.NotConnectedException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.PacketTypeFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.DefaultPacketExtension;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.PacketExtension;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.PacketExtensionProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.ProviderManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
```

Sample implementation:

```
/**
 * Sample Smack implementation of a client for GCM Cloud Connection Server. This
 * code can be run as a standalone CCS client.
 *
 * <p>For illustration purposes only.
 */

public class SmackCcsClient {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("SmackCcsClient");

private static final String GCM_SERVER = "gcm.googleapis.com";
private static final int GCM_PORT = 5235;

private static final String GCM_ELEMENT_NAME = "gcm";
private static final String GCM_NAMESPACE = "google:mobile:data";

static {

    ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider(GCM_ELEMENT_NAME, GCM_NAMESPACE,
        new PacketExtensionProvider() {
            @Override
            public PacketExtension parseExtension(XmlPullParser parser) throws
                    Exception {
                String json = parser.nextText();
                return new GcmPacketExtension(json);
            }
        });
}

private XMPPConnection connection;

/**
 * Indicates whether the connection is in draining state, which means that it
 * will not accept any new downstream messages.
 */
protected volatile boolean connectionDraining = false;

/**
 * Sends a downstream message to GCM.
 *
 * @return true if the message has been successfully sent.
 */
public boolean sendDownstreamMessage(String jsonRequest) throws
        NotConnectedException {
    if (!connectionDraining) {
        send(jsonRequest);
        return true;
    }
    logger.info("Dropping downstream message since the connection is draining");
    return false;
}

/**
 * Returns a random message id to uniquely identify a message.
 *
 * <p>Note: This is generated by a pseudo random number generator for
 * illustration purpose, and is not guaranteed to be unique.
 */
public String nextMessageId() {
    return "m-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}

/**
 * Sends a packet with contents provided.
 */
protected void send(String jsonRequest) throws NotConnectedException {
    Packet request = new GcmPacketExtension(jsonRequest).toPacket();
    connection.sendPacket(request);
}

/**
 * Handles an upstream data message from a device application.
 *
 * <p>This sample echo server sends an echo message back to the device.
 * Subclasses should override this method to properly process upstream messages.
 */
protected void handleUpstreamMessage(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {
    // PackageName of the application that sent this message.
    String category = (String) jsonObject.get("category");
    String from = (String) jsonObject.get("from");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, String> payload = (Map<String, String>) jsonObject.get("data");
    payload.put("ECHO", "Application: " + category);

    // Send an ECHO response back
    String echo = createJsonMessage(from, nextMessageId(), payload,
            "echo:CollapseKey", null, false);

    try {
        sendDownstreamMessage(echo);
    } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Not connected anymore, echo message is not sent", e);
    }
}

/**
 * Handles an ACK.
 *
 * <p>Logs a INFO message, but subclasses could override it to
 * properly handle ACKs.
 */
protected void handleAckReceipt(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {
    String messageId = (String) jsonObject.get("message_id");
    String from = (String) jsonObject.get("from");
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "handleAckReceipt() from: " + from + ",messageId: " + messageId);
}

/**
 * Handles a NACK.
 *
 * <p>Logs a INFO message, but subclasses could override it to
 * properly handle NACKs.
 */
protected void handleNackReceipt(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {
    String messageId = (String) jsonObject.get("message_id");
    String from = (String) jsonObject.get("from");
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "handleNackReceipt() from: " + from + ",messageId: " + messageId);
}

protected void handleControlMessage(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "handleControlMessage(): " + jsonObject);
    String controlType = (String) jsonObject.get("control_type");
    if ("CONNECTION_DRAINING".equals(controlType)) {
        connectionDraining = true;
    } else {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Unrecognized control type: %s. This could happen if new features are " + "added to the CCS protocol.",controlType);
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a JSON encoded GCM message.
 *
 * @param to RegistrationId of the target device (Required).
 * @param messageId Unique messageId for which CCS will send an
 *         "ack/nack" (Required).
 * @param payload Message content intended for the application. (Optional).
 * @param collapseKey GCM collapse_key parameter (Optional).
 * @param timeToLive GCM time_to_live parameter (Optional).
 * @param delayWhileIdle GCM delay_while_idle parameter (Optional).
 * @return JSON encoded GCM message.
 */
public static String createJsonMessage(String to, String messageId,
        Map<String, String> payload, String collapseKey, Long timeToLive,
        Boolean delayWhileIdle) {
    Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    message.put("to", to);
    if (collapseKey != null) {
        message.put("collapse_key", collapseKey);
    }
    if (timeToLive != null) {
        message.put("time_to_live", timeToLive);
    }
    if (delayWhileIdle != null && delayWhileIdle) {
        message.put("delay_while_idle", true);
    }
  message.put("message_id", messageId);
  message.put("data", payload);
  return JSONValue.toJSONString(message);
}

/**
 * Creates a JSON encoded ACK message for an upstream message received
 * from an application.
 *
 * @param to RegistrationId of the device who sent the upstream message.
 * @param messageId messageId of the upstream message to be acknowledged to CCS.
 * @return JSON encoded ack.
 */
    protected static String createJsonAck(String to, String messageId) {
    Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    message.put("message_type", "ack");
    message.put("to", to);
    message.put("message_id", messageId);
    return JSONValue.toJSONString(message);
}

/**
 * Connects to GCM Cloud Connection Server using the supplied credentials.
 *
 * @param senderId Your GCM project number
 * @param apiKey API Key of your project
 */
public void connect(long senderId, String apiKey)
        throws XMPPException, IOException, SmackException {
    ConnectionConfiguration config =
            new ConnectionConfiguration(GCM_SERVER, GCM_PORT);
    config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);
    config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
    config.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(false);
    config.setSendPresence(false);
    config.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());

    connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
    connection.connect();

    connection.addConnectionListener(new LoggingConnectionListener());

    // Handle incoming packets
    connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {

        @Override
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Received: " + packet.toXML());
            Message incomingMessage = (Message) packet;
            GcmPacketExtension gcmPacket =
                    (GcmPacketExtension) incomingMessage.
                    getExtension(GCM_NAMESPACE);
            String json = gcmPacket.getJson();
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Map<String, Object> jsonObject =
                        (Map<String, Object>) JSONValue.
                        parseWithException(json);

                // present for "ack"/"nack", null otherwise
                Object messageType = jsonObject.get("message_type");

                if (messageType == null) {
                    // Normal upstream data message
                    handleUpstreamMessage(jsonObject);

                    // Send ACK to CCS
                    String messageId = (String) jsonObject.get("message_id");
                    String from = (String) jsonObject.get("from");
                    String ack = createJsonAck(from, messageId);
                    send(ack);
                } else if ("ack".equals(messageType.toString())) {
                      // Process Ack
                      handleAckReceipt(jsonObject);
                } else if ("nack".equals(messageType.toString())) {
                      // Process Nack
                      handleNackReceipt(jsonObject);
                } else if ("control".equals(messageType.toString())) {
                      // Process control message
                      handleControlMessage(jsonObject);
                } else {
                      logger.log(Level.WARNING,
                              "Unrecognized message type (%s)",
                              messageType.toString());
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error parsing JSON " + json, e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to process packet", e);
            }
        }
    }, new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class));

    // Log all outgoing packets
    connection.addPacketInterceptor(new PacketInterceptor() {
        @Override
            public void interceptPacket(Packet packet) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Sent: {0}", packet.toXML());
            }
        }, new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class));

    connection.login(senderId + "@gcm.googleapis.com", apiKey);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final long senderId = 1234567890L; // your GCM sender id
    final String password = "Your API key";

    SmackCcsClient ccsClient = new SmackCcsClient();

    ccsClient.connect(senderId, password);

    // Send a sample hello downstream message to a device.
    String toRegId = "RegistrationIdOfTheTargetDevice";
    String messageId = ccsClient.nextMessageId();
    Map<String, String> payload = new HashMap<String, String>();
    payload.put("Hello", "World");
    payload.put("CCS", "Dummy Message");
    payload.put("EmbeddedMessageId", messageId);
    String collapseKey = "sample";
    Long timeToLive = 10000L;
    String message = createJsonMessage(toRegId, messageId, payload,
            collapseKey, timeToLive, true);

    ccsClient.sendDownstreamMessage(message);
}

/**
 * XMPP Packet Extension for GCM Cloud Connection Server.
 */
private static final class GcmPacketExtension extends DefaultPacketExtension {

    private final String json;

    public GcmPacketExtension(String json) {
        super(GCM_ELEMENT_NAME, GCM_NAMESPACE);
        this.json = json;
    }

    public String getJson() {
        return json;
    }


    public String toXML() {
        return String.format("<%s xmlns=\"%s\">%s</%s>",
                GCM_ELEMENT_NAME, GCM_NAMESPACE,
                StringUtils.escapeForXML(json), GCM_ELEMENT_NAME);
    }

    public Packet toPacket() {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.addExtension(this);
        return message;
    }
}

private static final class LoggingConnectionListener
        implements ConnectionListener {


    public void connected(XMPPConnection xmppConnection) {
        logger.info("Connected.");
    }


    public void authenticated(XMPPConnection xmppConnection) {
        logger.info("Authenticated.");
    }


    public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
        logger.info("Reconnecting..");
    }


    public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reconnection failed.. ", e);
    }


    public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reconnecting in %d secs", seconds);
    }


    public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
        logger.info("Connection closed on error.");
    }

            public void connectionClosed() {
        logger.info("Connection closed.");
    }
}
}
```

Once I try to run it with using the below command

```
java SmackCcsClient
```

it gives me the below error stack.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jivesoftware/smack/SmackException$NotConnectedException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:    org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 6 more
```